# Remove left string after found specific word - PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem regarding regular expression. Let say I have a string like this:

```
/media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/abcd/planet/document/sola
```

I need to remove all the string before word sola and take the string from sola onwards. Meaning, the output it will be like this:

```
sola/path/anotherpath/../..
```

So how I'm gonna do that. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: so why use regex when you can just find the first occurrence of your (sub)string and just cut from that point on?

Comment: @mishu - Why use regex at all when you can use [`basename`](http://us3.php.net/basename)?

Comment: @GigaWatt because even if the first string in the example ends with "sola", in the second one it seems that the OP needs some parts that might exist after that word (and slashes are included), see `Meaning, the output it will be like this: sola/path/anotherpath/../..`

Comment: @mishu - Ah, that wasn't very clear given the first example text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string="/media/bcd44b6a-9c2e-4496-81da-b45d3c349c91/abcd/planet/document/sola-asda";
echo substr($string,strpos($string,"sola")+4);    // -asda
```

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it. I never thought this is the solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

use string explode

```
$string1 = "your string"          //url
$string2 = "the part you need";   //Sola
$string3 = "";                    //string with the result;
$strings = explode($string2, $string1);
$c = count($strings);
if($c < 2){
    echo "not found";
}else{
    $i = 1;
    while($i < $c){
        $string3 .= $string2.$strings[$i];
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: pretty strange solution, but I think that your array is `$strings`, not `$string` ..

Comment: that was a typo my bad :p